# TortoiseSVN: how to find a repository on the local machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, svn, repository, tortoise-svn

The question is how to find an SVN repository on the local machine in Windows7?
I know the green (if no changes) or red mark (if changed) should be displayed on that folder. However, how to find that folder on the computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for folders with `.svn` subfolder - it means that folder that has it is SVN repository.

Answer (score 2):

To show the repository that any working folder is derived from:

- Locate any `svn` working folder (working folders will have a `.svn` sub-folder).
- Right-click on the folder.
- Select  "properties" from the explorer context menu.
- Switch to the "subversion" tab.